# Can a defect be logged into any custom WI directly from MS Test Runner? if so how?

Tags: tfs

In VSTS 2010 – in MS Test Runner

A defect can be logged against a work item called “BUG” by default.

This bug will have all the details relevant to the test that is run like the information in the following tabs in workitem bug – details tab, System info tab , Test Cases tab, etc .,

Instead of logging defects in workitem “BUG” is it possible to log defects to any other custom workitem but still manage to hold all these details tab , system info tab , test cases tab, etc., into the custom WI.

Please refer the attachment .

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your custom work item type into the Microsoft.BugCategory category. Take a look at the command line tool witadmin in %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

The following blog post might help you:

- [VS2010 Work item categories](http://ognjenbajic.com/blog/2009/08/vs2010-work-item-categories.html)

If you want all the controls as well (like repro steps control), then you need to make sure the appropriate fields and form controls are copied over into the work item from the Microsoft work item definitions.